# How to keep the user logged in even after closing the app in ionic/angular project?

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am new to angular/ionic and I am assigned with a project where the user supposed to be logged in even after he close the application unless logging out. can anyone suggest me how to modify the following code?

login.page.ts

```
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../services/authentication/authentication.service';
import {
    ToastController,
    AlertController,
    NavController,
    ModalController,
    Platform,
} from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api/api.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { crm, environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data/data.service';
import { ToastService } from '../../services/toast/toast.service';
import { AlertService } from '../../services/alert/alert.service';
import { ForgotPasswordModalPage } from '../forgot-password-modal/forgot-password-modal.page';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
import { FcmService } from '../../services/fcm/fcm.service';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { LoadingService } from 'src/app/services/loading/loading.service';
import { ServerService } from 'src/app/services/server/server.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { AppComponent } from '../../app.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    development: boolean;
    counts: number = 0;
    platformName: string;
    settings: any;

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthenticationService,
        public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private api: ApiService,
        private router: Router,
        private alert: AlertService,
        private dataService: DataService,
        private toast: ToastService,
        private navCtrl: NavController,
        private modalCtrl: ModalController,
        private device: Device,
        private fcmService: FcmService,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private loadingService: LoadingService,
        private server: ServerService,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController,
        private platform: Platform,
        private app: AppComponent,
    ) {
        this.initForm();
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setupServerUrl();
    }

    async setSettings() {
        console.log('settings called in appcomp');
        // check if in storage get it from storage
        this.dataService.getStorageData('settings').then((data) => {
            if (data != null) {
                this.settings = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log('seetings from storage:', this.settings);
                // this.dataService.setData('settings', this.settings)
            } else {
                // not found in storage get from api
                this.getSettingsApi();
            }
        });
    }

    async getSettingsApi() {
        // this.loadingService.loading();
        let mainLogos = document.getElementsByClassName('logo');
        for (let i = 0; i < mainLogos.length; i++) {
            mainLogos[i].setAttribute('src', 'assets/img/spinner.gif');
        }
        await this.api.get(crm.SETTINGS).subscribe((res) => {
            console.log('the api is ', this.api.url);
            // Note the api I supposed to get
            console.log('setting from appcomp api: ', res);
            if (res['code'] === '000') {
                this.settings = res;
                // this.dataService.setData('settings', this.settings)
                console.log('settings from appcomp done');
                this.dataService.setStorageData('settings', res);

                for (let i = 0; i < mainLogos.length; i++) {
                    mainLogos[i].setAttribute('src', this.settings.image_id.src);
                }
                // this.loadingService.dismissLoading();
            }
        });
    }

    // async setSettings() {
    //   console.log('settings from login')
    //   await this.dataService.getStorageData('settings').then( data => {
    //     console.log('seetings from storage: ', data)
    //     if (data != null) {
    //       this.settings = JSON.parse(data);
    //       this.dataService.setData('settings', this.settings)
    //     }else { // not found in storage get from api
    //       this.api.get(crm.SETTINGS).subscribe(res => {
    //         if (res['code'] === '000') {
    //
    //           this.settings = res
    //           this.dataService.setData('settings', this.settings)
    //           this.dataService.setStorageData('settings', res);
    //           // this.settingsService.data = this.settings
    //
    //           // toolbar logo
    //           // let mainLogos = document.getElementsByClassName('logo')
    //           // for (let i = 0; i < mainLogos.length; i++) {
    //           //   mainLogos[i].setAttribute('src', this.settings.image_id.src)
    //           // }
    //         }
    //       })
    //     }
    //   })
    // }

    // Note : server set up and function coming from server.service
    setupServerUrl() {
        this.dataService.getStorageData('url').then((res) => {
            if (res) {
                this.server.url = JSON.parse(res);
                console.log('server', res);
                console.log('server result123: ', this.server.url);
                console.log('login result123: ', this.server.login_url);
                this.server.login_url = JSON.parse(res);
                console.log('login', res);

                // console.log('have result serve url:', this.server.url);
                // console.log('have result login url:', this.server.login_url);
                this.getApiDomain('https://oasis.api.app360.my/');
            } else {
                console.log('empty result url:', this.server.url);
                this.getApiDomain('oasis.member.app360.my');
            }
        });
    }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        
        if (this.server.login_url === this.server.login_dev) {
            
            this.development = true;
        }
        if (this.server.login_url === this.server.login_prod) {
        
            this.development = false;
        }
        // this.setup()
        //       this.development = true;
        //       break;
        //     case this.server.prod:
        //       this.server.url = this.server.prod // added by me
        //       this.development = false;
        //       break;
        //   }
        // })
    }

    initForm() {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            email: [
                '',
                Validators.compose([
                    Validators.pattern('.+@.+\\..+'),
                    Validators.required,
                ]),
            ],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    }

    async getApiDomain(urlDomain: String) {
        console.log('beforeeee', this.server.url);
        await this.api
            .getBeforeLogin(crm.API_DOMAIN, '', '?url=' + urlDomain)
            .subscribe((res) => {
                if (res['code'] === '000') {
                    // console.log('resulttt',res['domain'])

                    this.server.url = 'https://' + res['domain'] + '/';
                    this.server.prod = 'https://' + res['domain'] + '/';

                    this.server.secret = res['api_key'];
                    // this.server.url = "http://oasis.api.app360.my/"
                    console.log('afterrrr', this.server.url);
                    // console.log('afterrrr', this.server.secret);

                    this.getSettingsApi();
                    

                    this.setHome();
                    this.checkToken();
                }
            });
    }

    // resolveSettings() {
    //   console.log('settings from login')
    //   this.api.get(crm.SETTINGS).subscribe(res => {
    //     if (res['code'] === '000') {
    //
    //       this.settings = res
    //       this.dataService.setData('settings', this.settings)
    //       // this.settingsService.data = this.settings
    //
    //       // toolbar logo
    //       let mainLogos = document.getElementsByClassName('logo')
    //       for (let i = 0; i < mainLogos.length; i++) {
    //         mainLogos[i].setAttribute('src', this.settings.image_id.src)
    //       }
    //
    //
    //     }
    //   })
    // }

    setup() {
        
        console.log('testttt', this.settings);

        // set toolbar color
        let toolbars = document.getElementsByTagName('ion-toolbar');
        for (let i = 0; i < toolbars.length; i++) {
            toolbars[i].setAttribute(
                'style',
                `--background: ${this.settings.colours.colour_menu_background}`,
            );
        }

        // toolbar logo
        let mainLogos = document.getElementsByClassName('logo');
        for (let i = 0; i < mainLogos.length; i++) {
            mainLogos[i].setAttribute('src', this.settings.image_id.src);
            console.log('wahaha', this.settings.image_id.src);
        }

        let button = document.getElementsByClassName('login-btn')[0];
        button.setAttribute(
            'style',
            `--background: ${this.settings.colours.colour_button1};
      --color: ${this.settings.colours.colour_menu_font}`,
        );

        console.log('endend');
    }

    async login(form) {
        await this.loadingService.loading();
        form.platform = this.device.platform;
        form.device_type = this.device.model;
        form.platform_token = this.device.uuid;
        form.push_token = this.fcmService.pushToken;
        console.log('form', form);
        await this.api.post(crm.LOGIN, form).subscribe((res) => {
            this.loadingService.dismissLoading();
            console.log('login', res);
            if (res.code === '000') {
                console.log('code', res.code);
                this.toast.showToast('Login Successful');
                //proceed with auth
                this.doAuth(res);
            } else {
                // let message = res.status+':'+res.statusText+'<br/>'+res.error.code+':'+res.error.message
                this.alert.showAlert({
                    header: 'Error: ' + res.error.code,
                    message: res.error.message,
                });
                console.log('error', res);
            }
        });
    }

    async forgotPassword() {
        console.log('do forgot password');

        let modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
            component: ForgotPasswordModalPage,
            cssClass: 'forgot-password',
        });

        return await modal.present();
    }

    doAuth(data) {
        console.log('from do auth: ', data);
        this.authService.login(data).then((res) => {
            if (res) {
                
                this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/tabs/tabs/home');

                console.log('doauth', data);
            }
        });
    }

    counter() {
        this.counts++;
        console.log(this.counts);

        if (this.counts >= 8) this.presentPrompt(); //TODO: change to 8
    }

    async presentPrompt() {
        this.counts = 0;
        const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
            header: ' ',
            inputs: [
                {
                    name: 'passcode',
                    placeholder: 'Passcode',
                    type: 'password',
                },
            ],
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    role: 'cancel',
                    handler: (data) => {
                        console.log('Cancel clicked');
                    },
                },
                {
                    text: 'Ok',
                    handler: (data) => {
                        
                        this.api
                            .getBeforeLogin(crm.SWITCH, null, `?passcode=${data.passcode}`)
                            .subscribe((res) => {
                                if (res['code'] == '000') {
                                    this.changeServer();
                                    console.log('Switched');
                                    this.toast.showToast('Switched');
                                    // this.loadingService.dismissLoading();
                                } else {
                                    this.alert.showAlert({
                                        header: 'Error: ' + res['code'],
                                        message: res['error'],
                                    });
                                    console.log('error', res);
                                }
                            });
                    },
                },
            ],
            cssClass: 'alertCustomCss',
            backdropDismiss: false,
        });

        await alert.present();
    }

    changeServer() {
        this.server.switchURL();
        switch (this.server.login_url) {
            case this.server.login_prod:
                this.development = false;
                // this.api.url = this.server.prod;
                this.server.login_url = this.server.login_prod;
                console.log('api url', this.server.login_url);
                break;
            case this.server.login_dev:
                this.development = true;
                this.server.login_url = this.server.login_dev;
                console.log('api url', this.server.login_url);
                break;
        }
        this.checkDownload();
        // Note :
        this.getApiDomain('https://oasis.api.app360.my/');
        // this.getApiDomain('com.apppay.cohibacustomer');
    }

    async checkDownload() {
        await this.dataService.getStorageData('stats_for_dev').then((res) => {
            if (!res) {
                let params = {};
                if (this.platform.is('android')) {
                    this.platformName = 'android';
                } else if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
                    this.platformName = 'ios';
                } else {
                    this.platformName = 'web';
                }
                params['refno'] = moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmm');
                params['data'] = [
                    {
                        action_cd: 'install',
                        user_id: null,
                        item_id: this.platformName[0], // a for android, i for ios
                        cnt: 1,
                        created_ts: moment().format('YYYY-M-D'),
                    },
                ];
                
            } else {
                console.log('have stats', JSON.parse(res));
            }
        });
    }

    async setHome() {
        await this.api.get(crm.HOME).subscribe((res) => {
            console.log('home>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ', res);
            this.dataService.setStorageData('home', res);
            this.dataService.setData('home', res);
            return res;
        });
    }

    async checkToken() {
        await this.dataService.getStorageData('member').then((res) => {
            if (res != null) {
                let token = res ? JSON.parse(res) : null;
                token = token['secret'] ? token['secret'] : null;
                if (token) {
                    this.authService.authenticationState.next(true);
                    if (this.server.url != this.server.check_url) {
                        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/tabs/tabs/home');
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    this.authService.authenticationState.next(false);
                    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

authentication.service.ts

```
import { Platform, NavController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Storage } from "@ionic/storage";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { DataService } from "../data/data.service";
import { ObservablesService } from "../observable/observables.service";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx";
import { Badge } from "@ionic-native/badge/ngx";
import { ServerService } from "../server/server.service";

const TOKEN_KEY = "auth-token";

export interface OcOAuth {
  success: number;
  error: any;
  data: {
    access_token: string;
    expire_in: number;
    token_type: string;
  };
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private plt: Platform,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private observable: ObservablesService,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private badge: Badge,
    private server: ServerService
  ) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkToken();
    });

    this.observable.unread().subscribe((res) => {
      this.badge.set(res);
      console.log("observed unread", res);
    });
  }

  async checkToken() {
    await this.storage.get("member").then((res) => {
      if (res != null) {
        let token = res ? JSON.parse(res) : null;
        token = token["secret"] ? token["secret"] : null;
        if (token) {
          this.authenticationState.next(true);
          if (this.server.url != this.server.check_url) {
            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("/tabs/tabs/home");
          }
          // console.log('server url: ', this.server.url);
          //
        } else {
          this.authenticationState.next(false);
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  login(data) {
    return this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, "Bearer 1234").then(() => {
      console.log("auth login", TOKEN_KEY);
      this.dataService.setStorageData("member", data);
      this.dataService.setData("member", data);
      // this.dataService.setStorageData('profile', data.user)
      this.observable.user.next(data.user);
      this.authenticationState.next(true);
      return true;
    });
  }

  logout() {
    return this.storage.remove("member").then(() => {
      this.badge.clear();
      this.authenticationState.next(false);
    });
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticationState.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your code is so long that can not help with that but i can explain what u must do the concept is when you logged in successfully u must get a token and store that.
After at app openning you must check that stored token. If that token still available u can navigate to main screen. Else u must navigate to ur login page.

```
login() {
   const attempt = login(username,pw) 
   if(attempt.status === 200) { 
   //if username and pw is correct web service must be return token
   this.storage.set("token", attempt.token)
   navigate("where u want")
} else {
   //Error when username or pw wrong.
}
```

If u using ionic u must check ur token in app.component.ts

```
const token = await this.storage.get("token")
const checkTokenIsAvailable = await checkToken(token)
if(checkTokenIsAvailable) {
    navigate("where u want")
    //Token is still available
} else { 
    navigate("login screen")
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I have posted here first time, will be carefull next time. thanks again

Comment: where do ppl store token normally? In remote cache or local?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: in mobile app u can store ur token in localstorage @alex

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.ts after platform is ready, add

```
if(this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated())
{
//Navigate to Home Page
}
else{
//Navigate to Login Page
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But somehow it doesn't work. it logs out in each reload

Comment: Check your router module. Maybe you're redirecting your app to LoginPage everytime.

Answer (score 0):

so I was able to solve the issue with the subscribe() method. Inside platfrom.ready I called this

```
this.authService.authenticationState.subscribe((state) => {
        if (state) {
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("/tabs/tabs/home");
        } else {
          this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("");
        }
      });
```